# Who was this character with Killmonger?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

At the start of *Black Panther* we see Killmonger

> robbing a museum with the help of a girl.

What do we know about this person?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Her name is [Linda](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Linda). She is played by [Nabiyah Be](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm8852246/). Not much is known beyond what we saw in the film.

[She was originally going to be the preexisting character](https://www.cbr.com/black-panther-nabiyah-be-nightshade/) [Tilda Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightshade_(Marvel_Comics)) but [*Luke Cage* ended up using the character first.](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Tilda_Johnson)